# Visual Studio Code - Executing code failed : Error: Pip module ptvsd is required for debugging cells. You will need to install it to debug cells

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

While debugging Jupyter Cell on Visual studio Code, It gives this error

**Executing code failed : Error: Pip module ptvsd is required for debugging cells. You will need to install it to debug cells.**

Yet running

```
import ptvsd
print(ptvsd.__version__)
```

returns 4.3.2

Comment: Hey Ravi. I'm a developer on this extension. Can I ask quick? Are you using the released version of this extension or are you on one of the more recent development builds? I know that we had an issue with this in recent dev builds.

Comment: Hi Ian, I am using the released version of this extension. Python extension version 2019.9.3.34911. Python version 3.6.7 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue. Turns out there is a file named queue.py existing in my source code folder. And it caused vs code failed to load PriorityQueue from queue module. Once removed the queue.py from my source code folder, the issue disappeared.